# Get information about Battery usage by an iOS application using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have integrated the firebase into my iOS application. I m using the firebase for Performance matrix and analytic purpose. Can firebase provide the information about battery usage by my application.

Comment: Firebase Performance is only to monitor API responses and startup time. Not device specific tasks like memory or battery usage.